# Java need regex to be only English characters. number and printable signs

Tags: java, regex, text

what is the syntax for those flowing conditions:

- only English characters(a-z, A-Z).
- numbers 0-9.
- space character.
- all printable keyboard signs(but just keyboard signs), for example: `~!@#$%^&*()_-+=;{[}]\|:',?/><,.`

friend told me what i am looking for called:

```
plainText.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "")
```

but this regex also print signs like the sign © and other languages characters.

Comment: What's a "keyboard sign"? Doesn't it depend on what's on your keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that should do it for you:

```
"[\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}\s]"
```

`\p{Alnum}` which is any alphanumeric character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9)

`\p{Punct}` which is any of the following characters: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

`\s` which is any whitespace character

---

For your specific case, here is the code that I assume you are looking for:

```
plainText.replaceAll("[\\p{Alnum}\\p{Punct}\\s]", "")
```

---

If you ever need to make a regex, [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a very useful link.